# Way to get a list of all of an object's associative references?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, runtime

In Objective-C 2.0, is there a runtime method that lists all of an object's associative references? I have an object with associative references to variables that are defined in a local scope, and I want to make sure I can still access them to release them in my dealloc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am not sure about a way to retrieve all of an object's associations, I don't believe you have to worry about releasing associated objects.  Apple's docs would seem to suggest they're taken care of when the object they're associated with is deallocated (i.e. an objects using the `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN` policy will be released accordingly.)

Would be interested to see a way to iterate over all associations though.

[Apple's doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAssociativeReferences.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH24-SW3) (specifically, the section "Creating Associations")